# Using a seperate class to handle sessions in PHP

Tags: php, session

I have two questions:

1. Would it be significantly slower to have a class for sessions in PHP? I mean, nearly duplicate with the current $_SESSIONS, except it's handled by a class using file IO, un/serialize, cookies and so forth... I'm just having issues with how PHP handles it's sessions.
2. Is it bad to have lots of files in one directory? Around 50k or 60k? Should I use a database or merge them into a lesser amount of files, or is it unnecessary?

Comment: What kind of issues do you have with PHP's session handling?

Comment: Nevermind. I think it should be fine actually. However, I'm still wondering if it's bad to have tons of files in one directory. I'd like it to where sessions are stored until they aren't modified for ~14 days...

Comment: an alternative class would not necessarily be significantly slower. 50-60k files sounds a bit much though. See e.g. here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40368/maximum-number-of-inodes-in-a-directory#

Comment: It also depends on your filesystem used. More info here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2419690/average-and-maximum-size-of-directories

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. It wouldn't be slower if properly designed, but i would highly recommend that you do not do that. Reinventing the wheel is never a good option. Thousands of people have already worked on PHP sessions and code written by thousands is by far less error prone than individually written code. You need to be knowledgeable of too many things to implement your own sessions system(including security etc..).
2. Generally speaking, files are faster for sequential data. However, a database is much more flexible and at times can be faster. I would personally use a database for sure. Messing with so many files would require that you write a whole frontend system. Why would you want to mess with that when a dbms offers that out of the box ?